# Low rank entangled states

Tags: specific-reference, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

In some recent works, I got the information that low rank mixed states need not be bound entangled. In particular, for the system $3\otimes 3$  there is no bound entangled states. Can anyone tell me how to prove it or give a proper reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There do exist bound entangled states in 3x3 dimensions, see P. Horodecki, Phys. Lett. A 232, 333 (1997), or the review http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702225 (Eq. 64). On the other hand, there are no bound entangled states in 2x2 and 2x3 dimensions (but again in 2x4).